# Insert a plot inside a paragraph

Tags: r, report, reporters

I am trying to find a method to wrap text around a plot in the word file I create using `ReporteRs` package. In word, we have an option called 'with text wrapping'. I am wondering whether we can create a similar result by nesting a `addPlot` function and `addParagraph`. Has anyone done this before? Please shed some guidance. Thank you

Comment: Using `addSection` and go with two columns may be a close option here. But I would like to get paragraph text wrap nicely around the plot.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid `ReporteRs` can't do that.
There is a new function ( `pot_img` in the latest release of `ReporteR`s) that let you concatenate text and images in a paragraph but it has no wrapping option.
~ From David (Author of the package)